# Levenshtein - grouping hotel names

Tags: php, string, algorithm, grouping, levenshtein-distance

I have to group some hotel into the same category based on their names. I'm using levenshtein for grouping, but how much I've tried, some hotel are leaved outside the category they supposed to be, or in another category.

For example: all these hotel should be in the same category:

=============================

Best Western Bercy Rive Gauche

Best Western Colisee

Best Western Ducs De Bourgogne

Best Western Folkestone Opera

Best Western France Europe

Best Western Hotel Sydney Opera

Best Western Paris Louvre Opera

Best Western Hotel De Neuville

=============================

I'm having a list with all hotel names( like 1000 rows ). I also have how they should be grouped.
Any idea how to optimize levenshtein, making it more flexible for my situation?

```
$inserted = false;
foreach($hotelList as $key => $value){
    if (levenshtein($key, $hotelName, 2, 5, 1) <= abs(strlen($key) - strlen($hotelName))){
        array_push($hotelList[$key], trim($line));
        $inserted = true;
    }
}
// if no match was found add another entry
if (!$inserted){
    $hotelList[$hotelName] = array(
            trim($line)
        );
}
```

Comment: You really should provide your actual code.

Comment: One option would be to add a `chain` or `company` column to your database table

Comment: Would have thought levenshtein is pretty optimized- you probably just want to write a different algorithm.

Comment: Big practical question is- do you allready know the hotel names?

Comment: I've edited the post. I have a sample list with hotels, and how they should be grouped.

Comment: Could you clarify? "I also have how they should be grouped.". So how do you have a problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have a sample list and I must write some code to group those items as they should. The code will be used next for a bigger list. Right now, I can't group those names with levenshtein properly.

Comment: No. Levenshtein will not give you a good clustering for hotel names. Levenshtein can be understood as computing this problem: "Supose in a text editor and I want to turn string A into string B. How many times am I going to have to press the keyboard? (Or thereabouts)." What else have you tried? There would be one or two options and trade-offs depending on your required accuracy.

Comment: Hotels should be grouped in the database by parent company/owner as @MarkBaker says.

Comment: Yes but where in the question does it say that the OP has access to the "parent company/owner" data? I suspect OP would like to hear how you'd get hold of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll wade in with my thoughts. Firstly, grouping or "clustering" data like this is a pretty big topic, I won't really go into it particularly but perhaps point things in an ideal direction.

You did a brilliant thing by normalizing Levenshtein on the length of the strings compared- that's exactly right because you avoid the problem that the length of the string would overdetermine the similarity in many cases.

But the algorithm didn't solve the problem. For a start, we want to compare words. "Bent Eastern French Hotels" is obviously very different to "Best Western French Hotels", yet it would score better than "Best Western Paris Bed and Breakfasts", say. The intution to grasp here is that your *tokens* shouldn't be *characters* but **words**.

I like @saury's answer, but I'm not sure about the assumption at the beginning. Instead, let's start with something nice and easy often called "[bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)". We then implement a [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_trick) trick, which would allow you to idetify the key phrases based on the intuition that the least used words contain the most information.

If you subscribe to the idea that hotel brand names are near the beginning you could always skew on their proximity to the start of the string too. Thing is, your groups will as likely end up being "France" as "Best" / "Western" (but not "hotel"- why?).

You want your results to be more accurate?

From here on in, we're gonna have to take a step up to some serious algorithms- enjoy surfing the many stack overflow topics. My instinct is that I bet many hotel names *aren't* branded at all, so you'll need different categories for them too. And my instinct is *also* that the number of repeated words in hotel names is going to be relatively slim- some words will be frequent members of hotel names. These facts would be problems for the above. In this case, there's a really popular (if cliched for SO) technique called k-means, a fun introduction to which would be to extend an algorithm like [this](http://phpir.com/clustering) (*very* bravely written in php) to take your chosen *n* keyphrases as the *n* dimensions of the cluster, then take the majority components of the cluster center-points as your categorization tags. (That would eliminate "France", say, because hits for "France" would be spread across the n-dimensional space pretty evenly).

This is probably all a bit much to take on for something that would seem like a small problem- but I want to emphasize that if your data isn't structured, there really aren't any short-cuts to doing things properly.

Answer (score 0):

what levenshtein distance value do you take as the delta between words to be treated as part of same group ? Seems that you tend to group hotels based on the initial few words and that will require a different approach altogether (like do dictionary sort , compare current string with next  strings etc). However if your use-case still requires to calculate  levenshtein distance then I would suggest you to sort the Strings based on their length and then start comparing each string with other strings of similar length (apply you own heuristic to what you consider as 'similar' like you may say isSimilar = Math.abs(str1.length - str2.length) < SOME_LOWEST_DELTA_VALUE or something like that)

Comment: Hmm.. i was thinking about the initial assumption that the hotel brand names will appear at the beginning. That would lead to a great approach as you describe, but is that assumption really true? I guess only OP can say.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis in general.